# How to check compiled linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, kernel

I am new to Linux Kernel Development. I have got the linux source code and added a Hello World system call just to get started. But now I am not able to figure out how to go about testing this code. How can I run the changed kernel?

I think I can use VirtualBox to check, but would not I have to make a new iso everytime I make a change and compile the kernel?

Sorry for asking such a naive question, but I am very confused here

Comment: "and added a Hello World system call just to get started". **What**?

Comment: I meant I added a system call which will just print Hello World. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Yes, that was clear, but why did you add a _system call_? We don't do that.

Comment: Look at this blog. sample system call is added and tested in QEMU environment. http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.com/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a `qemu` virtual machine with an external kernel, so you don't need to keep modifying a disk image to test your kernel. For example:

```
qemu-kvm -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd initramfs.gz -append "console=ttyS0" -nographic
```

That example comes from [this article](http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/02/near-instant-kernel-development-cycle.html) which contains a lot of information on how to set up a development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I downloaded the latest QEMU and installed it, but there is no option like qemu-kvm

Comment: You couldn't find QEMU and KVM pre-packaged for your system? You can run the kernel with just `qemu`, but it will be slower since it doesn't benefit from hardware assisted virtualization. It might be fast enough though; try it.

Comment: I am  using qemu to run the linux image. I am getting the QEMU monitor. However, I want to see if I can use my new system call and so write a C code for it, but I do not know how to write a C code in the virtual machine, since QEMU monitor does not allow me to do that

Comment: Did you check the qemu docs? There are many ways you can interact with the VM: you can connect to a serial port or see the VGA output in a GUI window. The qemu monitor is for stuff like stopping the VM, hotplugging devices etc